# Naked Root Domain Hosting

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

The usual approach calls for pointing `mysite.com` to `www.mysite.com`.

But suppose that I would like *not* to redirect. In other words, I would like to set up a naked root domain, without setting up any sub-domains, not even `www.mysite.com`.

I am using Route53 and S3. Presumably I would need just one hosted zone (`mysite.com`). Do I still need **two** buckets (`mysite.com` and `www.mysite.com`) or can I set up just mysite.com?

Comment: You could use two buckets (one empty, with redirection rule only) or one bucket and one CloudFront distribution.

Comment: "You could use..." all right, but do I need to? Can I simplify things to a single bucket?

Comment: not without redirection AFAIK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the bucket, named for your domain name.  The bucket name *has to match exactly* the address that shows in the browser's address bar.

Then, create an `A` record at the root (apex) of the domain in Route 53, leaving the hostname empty, selecting "Yes" for `Alias`, then select the bucket in the drop down list.

That is all you have to do.

If you create a "www" `CNAME` pointing to the domain name itself, this will not work with S3 web site hosting, because the bucket name won't match what's in the address bar of the browser (and a CNAME does not cause the browser to change the address bar to the target).

Everything in DNS that points to S3 must have a corresponding bucket that matches the DNS entry.  That's how it was designed.

Because people are often very prone to typing "www" in front of web site hostnames, you *probably should* create a second bucket with "www."+your domain name as the bucket name, then configure that bucket to redirect all requests to the root domain name, and set an additional `Alias` record on S3 -- because that way if a user types "www.example.com" into their browser, it will hit the second bucket and redirect -- by changing the browser's address bar -- to the root domain... which almost certainly is what you actually want, from a usability perspective.

Comment: I had understood that there is an approach that uses one hosted zone, one bucket, and *four* record sets for the hosted zone. This new (http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2012/12/root-domain-amazon-s3-website.html) method is simpler than the 2HZ+2B method. In the 2HZ+2B typing mysite.com as the URL lands one in www.mysite.com. In the 1HZ+1B+4RS method, it's the other way around: typing www.mysite.com lands one on mysite.com. I even got it to work that way (but only briefly ;). Please take a look at and comment on the diagram at http://stackoverflow.com/q/30792472/704972

Comment: You only ever needed one hosted zone, two records, one at the apex, one with www (and of course ns and soa).  Two hosted zones makes no sense *at all*.  Werner Vogels mentions only one bucket, because the "www" web site is not hosted in S3.  He created a bucket (named for the site, without www) and is using that to redirect to "www".  If you want your site hosted in S3, add another bucket.  There's only one solution, here, with S3, if you don't have an external server to handle the redirection from "alternate hostname" to "preferred hostname."

Comment: I don't believe you genuinely got it to work that way -- I suspect caching was involved, so you bounced off of old config onto new config, which would explain why it worked briefly.

Comment: I agree. Caching was surely in the way, though as false success rather than false failure.

Comment: This link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-bucket.html is the basis for the 2 Buckets. I'm looking for the URL reference for the two hosted zones (mysite.com and www.mysite.com). The objective of the two hosted zones is to make www.mysite.com the canonical site. Facebook uses something like this. If you point to facebook.com, you are directed to www.facebook.com (even though, on S3, the actual bucket would be named facebook.com).

Comment: That still does not require two hosted zones.  I welcome the link, but I suspect it is either technically inaccurate, or includes some kind of additional factor... but no, on S3, the final address in the address bar *absolutely* must exactly match the bucket name, so your conclusion that the "www.example.com" canonical host would work with content in the "example.com" bucket is not accurate.

Comment: What I understood from the docs and blogs that use two hosted zones and two buckets is that redirection is not triggered between the hosted zones (these have Alias records and no CNAME records). Redirection happens from one bucket (www.mysite.com) to the other (mysite.com). THAT (?) redirection DOES NOT (?) change the URL in the address bar. Effectively, the bucket redirect behaves (?) like a soft link on a unix file system. One sees the source, not the target. I inserted question marks where my understanding is still shaky.

Comment: All of your points marked with (?) are the opposite of what actually happens.  This is not as complicated or confusing as you seem to be trying to make it.

Answer (score -1):

> Edit after some testing on one of my extra domains.  The information
>   posted below is incorrect.  I'll leave this here so others don't follow down this incorrect path.

### --------------------------------

---

That's what CNAME records do for you.  Just add a CNAME for 'www' that goes to yourdomain.com

Both www.yourdomain.com and yourdomain.com will work in the browser without any redirection.

in Route53 it will look like this.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful image. Let me make sure I understand. This image is for the hosted zone mydomain.com (not www.mydomain.com). Is that right? I'm also not clear: do I need two hosted zones of just one? And do I need two buckets or will one suffice?

Comment: Still unsure about the name of the bucket. I know it must match the name of the hosted zone, but should the bucket in this case be called mysite.com or www.mysite.com?

Comment: bucket should be named base domain name just "mysite.com"  the hosted zone should be for "mysite.com"   that hosted zone will have the S3 alias setup and ALSO the CNAME of "www"

Comment: Incorrect.  The hostname sent by the browser must exactly match the name of the bucket, and `CNAME`s do not cause the browser to change what it sends.  That's the whole point of using a second bucket to do the browser redirection...

Comment: Thanks for the info @Michael-sqlbot . I tested on an extra domain and was not able to get the CNAME to work as I thought it would above.  I edited my answer above to note that the information is NOT correct.  Can you post a correct answer as an answer so the questioner can mark it and this question will have it noted.