# An illustration of AWS hosted zones and buckets

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

After more than a few experiments with hosted zones and buckets, it seems I'm getting failures due to unexpired caches even though I may well have set up everything correctly. Before proceeding, I'd like to summarize using two sketches the lengthy (and frankly, tedious) AWS documentation, and ask whether these are indeed correct. At this time I only care about correctness, but I'm also curious whether the two are functionally equivalent.

[image: hosted zones and buckets]

For both options I'm not documenting that:

- the files have been uploaded and made public on the bucket mysite.com, and
- the hosted zones also have NS and SOA records.

There is also a third method using 2 Hosted Zones, 2 Buckets, 1 Alias Record Set, and 1 CNAME that I'm leaving out.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish? For example, is your goal merely to have mysite.com AND www.mysite.com point to an Amazon S3 bucket with Static Website Hosting enabled?

Comment: Yes, exactly, just static hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend:

- In Amazon S3, create a bucket named `mysite.com`
- In Amazon Route 53, create a Hosted Zone for mysite.com (and of course, purchase the domain name, or point the current domain name to Route 53)
- In Route 53, create an A Record for the apex of `mysite.com` using "Alias = Yes", with the Alias Target set to the endpoint of the Amazon S3 static website hosting (eg `mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com`)
- In Route 53, create a CNAME Record for `www.mysite.com` and point it to `mysite.com`

This is similar to Option 1, but `www.mysite.com` would be pointing to `mysite.com` (rather than the reverse).

Comment: By "In Route 53, create a CNAME Record for www.mysite.com and point it to mysite.com" you mean "In Route 53, create a CNAME Record for the hosted zone mysite.com and set its Name to www.mysite.com and its Value to www.mysite.com.s3-website-region.amazonaws.com"; is that right?

Comment: Okay, to clarify: In the Hosted Zone `mysite.com`, create a Recordset with a Name of `www.mysite.com`, Type of CNAME and Value of `mysite.com`. When somebody resolves `www.mysite.com`, Route 53 will use the CNAME record to re-start the domain name resolution to use `mysite.com`. This is required because S3 uses the domain name to identify the bucket, so the DNS name being resolved must match the bucket name.

Comment: Well.. as I was writing my last comment I did what I was describing on two (unrelated/unconnected) domains. Now (8 hours later) redirection from www.mysite.com to mysite.com works fine on one but gives me "404 Not Found. Code: NoSuchBucket. Message: The specified bucket does not exist. BucketName: www.mysite.com" on the other. Clearly a caching issue. I'll now do what you describe in your comment, but presumably I have to wait 48 hours to be certain it works (I took, perhaps unwisely, the default TTL).